# How to post c# model and JSON string at same time in single ActionMethod

Tags: c#, jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

This is my action method which is supposed to receive a customer object and a string of json, I need both to be posted in same Action Method however,

```
public ActionResult CreateNewCustomer(Customers customers, string model)
{
  //....Codes omitted 
}
```

I tried posting using AJAX like here,

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
   url: url,
   data: { customers: $("#formtopost").serialize(), model: JSON.stringify(jsonToPost) }, 
    success: function (data) {
    alert(data); 
    }
  });

e.preventDefault();
```

But with this approach The customers object is always being `null`, Either I have to exclude `model` string or `customers` object. Please help me how can I receive both in same Action Method like mentioned above.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: your json parameter name and action one have to match, change in action parameter from ``customer`` to ``customers``

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Ohh I am sorry, This was my mistake while posting question but it's sure both are same. Now I edited my question. Please help me.

Comment: You need to add `[HttpPost]` for your action method.

Comment: @Bharadwaj It is there and I am well receiving the `model` string but only `customers` is null.

Comment: what is the value in `$("#formtopost")`? is it not the html element?

Comment: try to add `dataType: 'json', contentType: 'application/json',` in your ajax call, sorry I've not tested it, I'm little bit busy now. And please do this if above code will not work:  `customers: $("#formtopost", this).serialize(),`

Comment: @Bharadwaj no - that's not what `[HttpPost]` does.  You only need this if there are other methods with the same name and in that case you want to add `[HttpGet]` to the get methods.  To save you looking it up, the `[HttpPost]` (get/delete/etc) attributes *limit* the action to that verb, they do not say it's a post method - it's always a post method unless there's a restriction on it.

Comment: @MadhabDhakal Try changing the name from 'model' to something else (eg 'jsonmodel') in both controller and jquery.

Comment: @freedomn-m I tried already, But i think it's not the issue, I am receiving `model` string, only the `customers` object is null. If I post it excluding model. Even the object is being null. What may be the cause of it..If i submit the form normally it's submitted. Is it because the form could not be serialized ?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Hi, It seems the form could not be serialized, Do you have any idea how to debug that, What caused the failure for serializing the form ? any hints please.

Comment: The problem could also be with the deserialization.  Could you output the result of `$("#formtopost").serialize()` to the browser console and make sure the structure matches that of the Customers c# class?

Comment: I suggested the name change because the built-in modelbinder uses reflection to determine where to put values.  If any of the names are the same, you'll get strange results - ie if Customers model contained a 'model'  (or Model) property, it won't bind.

Comment: @freedomn-m Ohh thanks I changed that as your suggestion, and I will mind it not using the `model` keyword in future.

Comment: What is the output of `$("#formtopost").serialize()`?

Comment: @DoctorMick It's something like `Name=Madhab+Dhakal&GroupName=6&Address=Sanku+Rd.&Mobile=9843421584&Phone=9843421584&Email=madsangs53%40gmail.com&Extension=452&UserName=super&Password=superuser&IsActive=false` But there are extra fields in model but not set as required. I tried passing them as hidden as well.

Answer (score 0):

first you will define customer

```
var customer = {};
```

add data to the properties of customer like

```
customer.Name = "MyName";
```

and finally make ajax call to the controller

```
var Stringmodel = "*your string*";

$.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "/*your controller*/ * your action*",
                contentType: "application/json",
                data: JSON.stringify({ 'customers': customer , 'model': Stringmodel })
        })
```

Comment: add comment before marking negative so that i can improve my answer

Answer (score -1):

Append Querystring model to the url.
The data being passed must be formtopost serialized value.

```
e.preventDefault(); 
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url?model=jsonToPost,
    data: $("#formtopost").serialize(), 
    success: function (data) {
         alert(data); 
      }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I appreciate. This seems working, But beside that It's not only the matter of `model` string, If I post excluding `model`, I mean only the form by serializing it's still `null`. What may be the cause, Is it because form could not be serialized. If so how can I debug that ?

Comment: what is null? model or customers?

Comment: customers is null, model is fine, OK for temporary purpose i removed model, Even only the form is also null do you have any idea ?

Comment: Might be issue with keyvalue pair being binded. Can you check in developer tools what is the keyvalue pair being sent?And does the keys match the Customer properties

Comment: can you pls expalain why it is downvoted? the above solution works when you need to pass complex object and string and that is what was expected.

Comment: Leave a comment as why its downvoted. just downvoting without comment shows you have just done it without reason.And more over the OP guy left in the comment its working. so go through the conversation. Common, even you lose points!